# Convert Integer Column to Date in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have an Integer column called `birth_date` in this format: `20141130`

I want to convert that to `2014-11-30` in PySpark.

This converts the date incorrectly:

```
.withColumn("birth_date", F.to_date(F.from_unixtime(F.col("birth_date"))))
```

This gives an error: `argument 1 requires (string or date or timestamp) type, however, 'birth_date' is of int type`

```
.withColumn('birth_date', F.to_date(F.unix_timestamp(F.col('birth_date'), 'yyyyMMdd').cast('timestamp')))
```

What is the best way to convert it to the date I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the `birth_date` column from `Integer` to `String` before you pass it to the `to_date` function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("birth_date", F.to_date(F.col("birth_date").cast("string"), \
    'yyyyMMdd')).show()

+----------+
|birth_date|
+----------+
|2014-11-30|
+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code should work fine.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
raw_df.select('timestamp')\
.withColumn("as_date", psf.to_utc_timestamp(psf.from_unixtime(psf.col("timestamp"),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'IST')).show(20)
```